# How to use an outer mock inside `impl_benchmark_test_suite`?

Tags: pallet, runtime, benchmarking, testing, mock

Hey valuable Substrate pros,

do you know a way to use `impl_benchmark_test_suite` inside another crate like the runtime? I have multiple pallets. There are no mocks inside these pallets. There is only one runtime mock in my project. Since `impl_benchmark_test_suite` needs the mock, I would like to find a way to call the benchmark tests in an outer crate like the runtime.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benchmark_tests {
    use super::*;
    use frame_benchmarking::impl_benchmark_test_suite;

    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
        my_pallet_1::Pallet,
        crate::mock::ExtBuilder::default().build(),
        crate::mock::Test,
        benchmarks_path = my_pallet_1::benchmarking,
    );

    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
        my_pallet_2::Pallet,
        crate::mock::ExtBuilder::default().build(),
        crate::mock::Test,
        benchmarks_path = my_pallet_2::benchmarking,
    );

    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
        my_pallet_3::Pallet,
        crate::mock::ExtBuilder::default().build(),
        crate::mock::Test,
        benchmarks_path = my_pallet_3::benchmarking,
    );
}
```

This produces that error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `::`

my_pallet_1::Pallet

no rules expected this token in macro call
```

EDIT:

Trying to use the benchmark test module inside the mock of the runtime:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benchmark_tests {
    use frame_benchmarking::impl_benchmark_test_suite;

    use my_pallet::Pallet;

    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
        Pallet,
        ExtBuilder::default().build(),
        Test,
        benchmarks_path = my_pallet::benchmarking,
    );
}
```

This produces this error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `)`
375 | /     impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
376 | |         Pallet,
377 | |         ExtBuilder::default().build(),
378 | |         Test,
379 | |         benchmarks_path = my_pallet::benchmarking,
380 | |     );
    | |_____^ no rules expected this token in macro call
```

EDIT 2:

I tried another approach: Just using the mock runtime and ExtBuilder from another pallet.

Inside my_pallet/benchmarking.rs:

```rust
impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, pallet_tests::ExtBuilder::default().build(), pallet_tests::Test);
```

Although ExtBuilder and Test is public in `pallet_tests` it produces the following error:

```
failed to resolve: could not find `ExtBuilder` in `pallet_tests`

could not find `ExtBuilder` in `pallet_tests`

cannot find type `Test` in crate `pallet_tests`
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem in your approach is using fully qualified paths for the first and fourth argument. Checking in [the docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_benchmarking/macro.impl_benchmark_test_suite.html#arguments) I found the following information:

> because of macro syntax limitations, neither Pallet nor benches can be paths, but both have to be idents in the scope of `impl_benchmark_test_suite`.

So I guess you might try doing something like this:

```rust
use my_pallet_1::{Pallet as Pallet1, benchmarking as bench1};

impl_benchmark_test_suite!(
    Pallet1,
    crate::mock::ExtBuilder::default().build(),
    crate::mock::Test,
    benchmarks_path = bench1
);
```

I haven't tested it though, it's just my suggestion based on the docs.

---

EDIT: This **doesn't work**, unfortunately. See comments.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. This error: `error: no rules expected the token ')'` and in addition this `warning: unused imports: `Pallet as Pallet1`, 'benchmarking as bench1'`.

Comment: Another error, which comes after doing this: `error[E0599]: no function or associated item named 'test_bench_by_name' found for struct 'my_pallet::Pallet' in the current scope`

Comment: I've tried to reproduce what you attempt to do, but with my crate, and got the same error. So after some digging in Substrate I learned that `test_bench_by_name` is indeed implemented by the `benchmarks!` macro, but it has a `#[cfg(test)]` annotation, which AFAIR makes it invisible to other crates. :( You might take a look at the [source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/409167ef427e1b1b32a0cb9c05117e8fe73a7b1a/frame/benchmarking/src/lib.rs#L1126-L1151) and try to implement it manually, but I'm not sure if it's worth.

Comment: I see, that the code of `test_bench_by_name` is invisible without the feature `test`. But I could ensure, that the call of `impl_benchmark_test_suite` is in the scope of an enabled `test` feature too. Why isn't that visible then?

Comment: `test` doesn't work like other features in Rust. You can't use code from other crates annotated with `#[cfg(test)]`, even when the code using it would have `#[cfg(test)]` too.

Comment: I just found a way to get a better result with just ignoring `impl_benchmark_test_suite` and use the actual runtime config parameters with this script: `./target/release/my-node benchmark pallet --chain dev --execution=native --wasm-execution=compiled --heap-pages=4096 --pallet "*" --extrinsic "*" --steps 1 --repeat 0 --detailed-log-output`